# Java - Method program - using switch case with method

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

I'm writing a program that takes in the users birth information, year, month, day, hour, minute. The program is the following:

> Use the `getRangedInt` method to input the year (1965-2000), month
>   (1-12), Day*, hours (1 – 24), Minutes (1-59) of a person’s birth.
>
> Note: use a switch() conditional selector structure to limit the user
>   to the correct number of days for the month they were born in. For
>   instance if they were born in Feb [1-29], Oct [1-31].  HINT: there are
>   only a few groups here not 12 different ones!

I'm absolutely confused with the day part. I have managed to get everything else to work except understand what I'm supposed to do for the day.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int year, month, day, hour, minutes;
    String msg="";
    boolean done = true;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(done)
    {
        year = SafeInput.getIntInRange(in, "Enter the year you were born: ", 1965, 2000);       
        month = SafeInput.getIntInRange(in, "Enter your month of birth: ", 1, 12);
        day = SafeInput.getIntInRange(in, "Enter the day you were born: ", day, day);      
        hour = SafeInput.getIntInRange(in, "Enter the hour you were born in: ", 1, 24);
        minutes = SafeInput.getIntInRange(in, "Enter the minutes you were born: ", 1, 59);

        System.out.println("You were born: " + year + " , " + msg + " , " + hour + " hr. " + minutes + " mins. ");

        done = SafeInput.getYNConfirm(in, "Would you like to play again?");
    }
}
```

The `getIntInRange` just does a basic input to get the number in range.
I'm confused because I don't know how to do the range for the day since there is also supposed to be a switch used.

Comment: Why not just `1, 7` ? It's like any other option. (BTW `1, 59` for minutes makes no sense - it's either `1, 60` or `0, 59`)

Comment: @Elazar It's day of month, not day of week, and months have different lengths.

Comment: @Elazar But you're correct on the other part - minute 0 should be a valid choice.  (7:60 would be a rather weird time, so I think 0 is better than 60.)

Comment: I know it makes since but that is what we are told to do. This program is completely confusing me.

Comment: I do not like this requirement to use a switch there at all, especially encouraging to use fall-through.

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski It's a good exercise for switching actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange requirement.

It looks like what is requested from you looks like something like this:

```
int numberOfDays;
switch (month) {
case 1: // $FALL-THROUGH
case 3: // $FALL-THROUGH
case 5: // $FALL-THROUGH
case 7: // $FALL-THROUGH
case 9: // $FALL-THROUGH
case 11:
    numberOfDays = 31;
    break;
case 4: // $FALL-THROUGH
case 6: // $FALL-THROUGH
case 8: // $FALL-THROUGH
case 10: // $FALL-THROUGH
case 12:
    numberOfDays = 30;
    break;
case 2:
    numberOfDays = (0 == year / 4) ? 29 : 28;
    break;
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("month not 1-12");
} // switch (too long for my liking)
```

and then

```
day = SafeInput.getIntInRange(in, "Enter the day you were born: ", 1, numberOfDays);
```

This utilizes a fall-through construct available in switches, so if you meet a condition, you are going to execute until a return statement (or break/throw).

---

Please remember that the alternative is to have something like:

```
private static final Set<Integer> MONTHS_30_DAYS = Sets.newTreeSet(4, 6, 8, 10, 12);
private static final Set<Integer> MONTHS_31_DAYS = Sets.newTreeSet(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11);

public static int numberOfDays(int month, int year) {
   if (MONTHS_30_DAYS.contains(month)) {
      return 30;
   } else if (MONTHS_31_DAYS.contains(month)) {
      return 31;
   } else {
     return (0 == year / 4) ? 29 : 28;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `Sets.newTreeSet`?

Answer (score 0):

Here your day is dependent on the month entered. So firstly you'd want to take the month entered by the user as an Integer like you're doing now and proceed to use that number in a switch:

```
int month = 0;
int numberOfDays;

        switch (month) {
            case 1:  numberOfDays = DaysInJanuary;
                     break;
            case 2:  numberOfDays = DaysInFebruary;
                     break;
            case 3:  numberOfDays = DaysInMarch;
                     break;
            case 4:  numberOfDays = DaysInApril;
                     break;
            case 5:  numberOfDays = DaysInMay;
                     break;
            case 6:  numberOfDays = DaysInJune;
                     break;
            case 7:  numberOfDays = DaysInJuly;
                     break;
            case 8:  numberOfDays = DaysInAugust;
                     break;
            case 9:  numberOfDays = DaysInSeptember;
                     break;
            case 10: numberOfDays = DaysInOctober;
                     break;
            case 11: numberOfDays = DaysInNovember;
                     break;
            case 12: numberOfDays = DaysInDecember;
                     break;
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid month");
                     break;
        }
```

You can then proceed to set your variable for the max day range.

```
day = SafeInput.getIntInRange(in, "Enter the day you were born: ", 1, numberOfDays);
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: I guess that's really robust, in case they change the number of days in August again?

Comment: What is `DaysInDecember`? Looks like some kind of type name.

Comment: @user1803551 I assume it's a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're required to use switch statement, you can split months by the number of days in them. There will be 3 groups. Than you can use a switch statement as follows:

```
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
            return 31;

        case 2: {
            if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) 
                return 29; 
            else 
                return 28;
            }

        case 4:
        case 6:
            return 30;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("some error text");
    }
```

The switch statement in the example is not full, you should write a case statements for every month. Basically you're returning the upper value for day.

Comment: What is `if return`?

Comment: @user1803551 Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `day` range depends on the previous `month` number the user entered, so you have to check that in order to know which day range to display. What the hint tells you is that you don't need a different range of valid days for each month because some months share the same range. Here are the number of days in a month:

```
January     31
February    28/29
March       31
April       30
May         31
June        30
July        31
August      31
September   30
October     31
November    30
December    31
```

As you can see, there are only 3 groups and the assignment wants you to utilize *fallthrough* - when you don't `break` in a `switch`:

```
int upperDaysLimit;
switch(month) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    //...
    case 12: upperDaysLimit = 31;
             break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    // and so on
}
```

and now you can use that range limit on your days inquiry:

```
day = SafeInput.getIntInRange(in, "Enter the day you were born: ", 1, upperDaysLimit);
```

Comment: When you don't `break`, `return`, `throw` or otherwise stop execution.

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski What is that relevant to?